# How to keep msgbox always on top in vba?

Tags: vba, excel, msgbox

While my macro runs, I do my other works. But then when msgbox pops out stays behind my other windows.

How can I see it on top, when it pops out?

Thank you.

Comment: Put this line before the msgbox code AppActivate Application.Caption? Solutions discussed here https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/66245-ensure-msgbox-pops-up-top.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add system modal parameter `vbSystemModal`:

```
MsgBox "Your message!", vbSystemModal
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/msgbox-function

Comment: If your button has a defined style, you can also add `vbSystemModal` there, like `Style = vbOKOnly Or vbSystemModal` (this would make an Ok button come up in front of other windows)

Answer (score -1):

Add an exclamation mark to the message:

MsgBox "Your message!",6 +vbSystemModal, "Title of Msg..."